# jsfiddle layout broken: wrong input size. Where is the size stored?

Tags: html, css, layout, input, jsfiddle

I came across a weird bug with [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). The layout I get when I visit the site is completely broken. This bug happened when I dragged the vertical resize bar while my second display disconnected. See this the result:

[image: jsfiddle broken layout]

There is probably a way I can get this fixed from the inspector by resizing it manually, locating left panels and changing their width manually and than playing with the vertical resize bar; I'l keep investigating.

[image: jsfiddle column left with inspector]

**Where are the layout positions stored?**

Before asking this question, I tried to reset my cookies, I had a look into `local storage` and `session storage` (they were both empty). I know it's a local issue because jsfiddle is too awesome to break like that, it's not because of the code in the fiddle, I opened the fiddle in private navigation and worked like a charm.

[image: jsfiddle private navigation layout ok]

**Edit**: I fixed my issue by deleting `.column.left`, `#handler_vertical` appeared, I moved it and now data is fixed, but I still don't know where this is stored ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same issue and worked out that it was after I reduced the size of my browser window, I'd accidentally moved the vertical bar left, which caused this to 'disappear', so when I resized the window  to full, no vertical bar! 
To fix, I searched the inspector element for 'handler_vertical', and around this were column left and column right, with widths set inline. Simply remove these inline widths and it's back to normal.

Strange that some js is still adding itself even after clearing cache and cookies!!

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally deleted an HTML node in Chrome's inspector, which broke JSfiddle's layout.

When I reloaded the page, I was surprised to see the layout was still broken.

I cleared my cache and made a hard reload, but JSfiddle's layout was still broken!

The solution came out recently : **I changed Chrome's theme**... and it fixed JSfiddle.

Sometimes you just don't want to understand.

Comment: Ahaha, that's strange :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this was solved a while ago, but I just wanted to add that the FAQ acknoledges this and pasting `Layout.setWindowSizes(null)`into the browser console fixes the layout.

Source: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/faq.html

Answer (score 0):

Same just happened to me, reloading the site had no effect but deleting last cached elements made it